# Desktop user authentication via a touchscreen

Tags: facebook, authentication, desktop, touchscreen

As I understand it (and have also implemented) a user is required to interact with Facebook to enter their login details eg. through a web page embedded in desktop app.

Now I'm writing a desktop touchscreen app with a custom on screen keyboard (for entering info). But that's no good for the facebook user authentication.

Does facebook provide authentication/login dialogs that don't require keyboard entry of user details - eg. using an onscreen keyboard. They must do for mobiles, but what about web pages (embedded in a desktop app).

Are there versions that provide a touchscreen interface (with onscreen keyboard).

And if so, where do I find them?

Answer (score 0):

You need to embeded web browser with your desktop application.

It seem facebook authentication base on web application. Try to lookup this [flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#client-side-flow)

see also on Desktop Apps Section in : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/